# Restrict page access only can enter from a specified page?

Tags: asp.net

I am kind of new to ASP.NET.

I wonder is there any way to restrict user can only enter from a specify page?

Like, I have a Page A to let them enter some information, then when submit, I will use Response.Redirect to Page B.  But I don't want the user can go into Page B directly from URL....

If I use Session, then if the user didn't close the browser to end the session, the another user can just go into Page B directly...

Because the computer that access to these pages is using by the public, so I want to see if there is anyway to make sure they only do one way process? Can't go back to previous or jump to another page.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: As far as the downside to using session- you could implement the session/url-based solution described below- but you will still need *some* sort of time-based grace.

Comment: hmm session/url-based? I wonder do you mean like what you have described below, session with DateTime parameter and that DateTime should follows with a URL? so we can check does the URL valid?

Comment: Yes. You're query string would only contain the key/hash, but in session or your database you would store *when* you generated the key/hash so you can ensure it is not outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you control the other page, start a session and set a session variable to a value that can be reversed that only your server could (or should) create, much like serial keys. For example `72150166` because the sum of every second number equals the sum of every other number (7 + 1 + 0 + 6 = 2 + 5 + 1 + 6) but you could choose an algorithm as complex or as simple as you want. When the user navigates to the second page, check the session variable. This is not invincible security, but it is better than checking the referrer (especially since some browsers do not set it) and I imagine security based on coming from a certain page doesn't have to be that strict.

Edit: You should also add it to a database and link it with the particular user's IP so someone else can't use the same key.

Comment: To add to Minitech's proposition, you could also expire this key. This would add a further layer of security. (Like the URL key...same principle with expiration)

Comment: hmmm I see, so I might actually store a DateTime.Now + 1 min into session in Page A, then I can make sure that DateTime session is not expired in Page B.  Thanks! This should do what I want!

Comment: Yes- you'll need to store the key as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Request.UrlReferrer property in the Page Load of PageB to see which page is the request coming from. If the request is not coming from PageA then redirect the user to PageA.

Check this link for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx

**Note:** UrlReferrer is dependent on a request header and someone can set the header to mimic the request coming from PageA.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the page that redirects send some sort of specifically generated hash/key in the query string that expires quickly and/or once viewed. This should be a lot more solid on the security side.

You will still need some way to store this key or value producing the hash so you can validate it on the receiving end- I would think your DB.